# Filter Columns which have id in splitted String in sqlserver 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi i have String like This

```
 1;2;12;15;6;77;
```

which contain ids of table A
and table A is

```
 id     setcolumn     
  1     false
  2     false
  3     false 
  ...
```

and i want to set true each row have id in my input string.
So can anyone Help me about this?

Comment: [Enjoy.](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Comment: One time thing, or something your going to have to do a lot, like in a stored procedure?

Comment: Create a function which will split the string and return you the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

---

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    Id NVARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('1;2;12;15;6;77')

CREATE TABLE #Test2
(
    Id NVARCHAR(100),
    Setcolumn NVARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO #Test2 VALUES
(1, 'false'), (2, 'false'), (3, 'false'), (4, 'false')
```

---

**QUERY**

```
;WITH cte AS(
 SELECT   
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data  
 FROM  
 (
     SELECT  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Id, ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
     FROM  #Test
 ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a) 
)
UPDATE t
SET t.Setcolumn = 'true'
FROM cte 
JOIN #Test2 t ON cte.Data = t.Id

SELECT * 
FROM #Test2
```

---

**DEMO**

You can test it at <kbd>[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fa299/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
CREATE TABLE #tt(id INT, flag BIT)
INSERT INTO #tt VALUES (1,0),(2,0),(3,0)

DECLARE @S VARCHAR(max),
        @Split CHAR(1),
        @X XML

SELECT @S = '1;2;3;4;5',
        @Split = ';'

SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <s>' + REPLACE(@S,@Split,'</s> <s>') + '</s>   </root> ')

UPDATE tbl
SET tbl.flag=1
FROM #tt tbl 
    INNER JOIN(
    SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')
    FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c))k on tbl.id = k.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
Declare @tableA table( id int, setcolumn bit )
insert into @tableA values (1,0),(2,0),( 3,0)

declare @list varchar(200) = '1;2;12;15;6;77;' , @Delimiter varchar(1) = ';'

; with cte as 
(
SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
)

update @tableA 
set setcolumn = cte.Item
from
@tableA a join
cte on cte.Item = a.id

select * from @tableA
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a split function which you can use in future also.It will return a table of results. Use the result in where condition to update the Table A.
Reference to create the function:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

create Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text varchar(8000), @delimiter varchar(20))
RETURNS @Strings TABLE
(   
  position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  value varchar(8000)  
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @index int
SET @index = -1

WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)
  BEGIN 
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text) 
    IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0) 
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
          BREAK 
      END 
    IF (@index > 1) 
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))  
        SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
      END 
    ELSE
      SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))
    END
  RETURN
END
```

Query

```
declare @stringval nvarchar(max) = '1;2;12;15;6;77'
declare @spltval nvarchar(2) = ';'
update table A setcolumn  = true where id in
(select value from fn_split(@stringval,@spltval ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below one

```
Create table temp (id int,setcolumn varchar(10)) 
insert into  temp (id,setcolumn)
values(1,'false') 
insert into  temp (id,setcolumn)
values(2,'false') 
insert into  temp (id,setcolumn)
values(3,'false') 
insert into  temp (id,setcolumn)
values(4,'false') 
insert into  temp (id,setcolumn)
values(5,'false') 


declare @str varchar(100)
SET @str = '1;2;12;15;6;77' 
set @str = replace(@str,';',',')
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(100)

SET @SQl =  'UPDATE temp  SET setcolumn = ''TRUE'' where  id in (' +@STR+')'

exec sp_executesql @SQl
```